# Ant Iterate through files and search for expressions

Tags: ant

In Ant I would like to iterate through files and in each file's content i'm looking for some regexp. From the matches of the regexp I want to create a new file.

ie. I have 3 files:

A.txt

```
<root>
<node type="com.module.SomeModule" />
<node name="Test" />
</root>
```

B.txt

```
<root>
<node name="Apple" />
<node type="com.module.SomeModule2" />
<node type="com.module.SomeModule3" />
<strangenode id="green" />
</root>
```

C.txt

```
<root>
<node name="Apple" />
<strangenode id="green" />
</root>
```

And i want to create a file like this:

references.txt

```
com.module.SomeModule
com.module.SomeModule2
com.module.SomeModule3
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [XSLT task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) to parse the XML and generate a set of files containing the desired values, then use [concat task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) to assemble `references.txt` from the set of files output from XSLT.